# cannot find jpype even after successful installation

Tags: python, h2, jpype, jaydebeapi

I tried to install jpype by pip as follows

> sudo pip3 install JPype1-py3

but, I received a bunch of errors; the screenshot is attached.  [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5zFk.png)Then I installed manually that package, and when I run, it says: (the screenshot is also attached )
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVURN.png)

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jpype'

If you have experienced this problem before, please give me any idea or recommendations to fix it
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: May be this will solve the problem https://github.com/tcalmant/jpype-py3#debianubuntu

Comment: I tried to follow github.com/tcalmant/jpype-py3#debianubuntu, but still the same errors...

Comment: Can you add them too please, and could you try to install it using this https://github.com/tcalmant/jpype-py3#installation

Comment: How are you running it - can you post the full command line you're using?

Comment: Ok, actually it was installed I guess. However, when I run code, it still cannot find jpype

Comment: What I did is that: 1) git clone https://github.com/tcalmant/jpype-py3.git
2) sudo apt-get install g++ python3-dev 3) cd directory then sudo python3 setup.py install But it still shows me the error that  " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "jpype1" ,  i thought that it might be because of path, but i checked it  and it is right path I do not know it does not see jpype

Answer (score 1):

JPype-py3 branch has been deprecated for a while.  See https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html for current install instructions for the main distribution.